# Model uploaded to Cloud ML Engine won't create version, but runs locally

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-ml, google-cloud-ml-engine

I've trained a model that I want to serve in Google Cloud ML Engine. I've exported it using the SavedModel format required and tested it using the following:

```
gcloud ml-engine local predict --model-dir=saved/ --json-instances=one-record.json
```

The `saved/` dir only contains the `saved_model.pb` file, and there's only one line in `one-record.json`. The above command works and produces a prediction written to the console.

I've copied the contents of this directory to a cloud storage bucket (e.g. `gs://my-bucket/saved/`) and have attempted to create a version like so:

```
gcloud ml-engine versions create v1 --model=my-model --origin=gs://my-bucket/saved/ --runtime-version=1.0
```

The model exists and was created with `--enable-logging`, but no logs are produced in the StackDriver section of the console, or output on my local terminal. I get this error:

```
Creating version (this might take a few minutes)......failed.                                                                                                                       
ERROR: (gcloud.ml-engine.versions.create) Bad model detected with error:  "Error loading the model: Could not load model. "
```

Is there any way to debug this further? "**Could not load model**" is not very helpful, and the only [advice](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/how-tos/troubleshooting#troubleshooting_prediction) is to try testing locally, which works.

Comment: Which version of TensorFlow are you using locally?

Comment: @AllenLavoie 1.0.1

Comment: You may want to try deploying with --runtime-version=1.2; if that doesn't work, please email cloudml-feedback@ with your project/model/version names and we can help debug.

Comment: I'm using TensorFlow 1.2.1 and getting the same error.  Will email.